# Change Duplicate values index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like

```
+---------------------------+
|  | Name        | Id       |
| ------------------------- |
|  0 | nick        | 1      |
|  1 | john        | 2      |
|  2 | mick        | 3      |
|  3 | nick        | 4      |
|  4 | mick        | 5      |
|  5 | nick        | 6      |
+---------------------------+
```

And I want to reset the **Id** Index like

```
index | Name        | Id
-------------------------
 0    | nick        | 1
 1    | john        | 2
 2    | mick        | 3
 3    | nick        | 1
 4    | mick        | 3
 5    | nick        | 1
```

Comment: Did you try anything in particular? Any loop to output the array and calculate the Id? Perhaps even some pseudo code as to how you attempt to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) by `name` column:

```
df['Id'] = pd.factorize(df['Name'])[0] + 1
print (df)

   Name  Id
0  nick   1
1  john   2
2  mick   3
3  nick   1
4  mick   3
5  nick   1
```